# How to run a NODE.JS server on local wifi?

Tags: node.js, ip, port

So I've tried making my server listen on IP - 0.0.0.0 and on port 8080, then when I open up the browser (Chrome) and type https://192.168.0.1:8080/, Chrome says 'This site can’t be reached'. Although when I run the server in the CMD it starts working totally fine, which I think should be a sign for the server actually running somewhere.

Everyone's help is very appreciated!

Comment: What's the ip (internal, private ip) of the device that you're running the server on?

Comment: I'm running it on the same laptop where the server is, and the local IP is 127.0.0.1 as usual.

Comment: Right, that's your local ip for that device, but if you do ipconfig on windows or ifconfig on *nix, it will show your private ip on the network.  Then you can access your server from other devices on the same network using that private ip that's assign to the device that's hosting your server.  Then if you want to access your server from outside of the network, then you would need to find out your public ip from your internet service provider, and also configure your router to route accordingly to the correct device.

Comment: This is what I get from it and that's why I type https://192.168.0.1:8080/     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.102
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Comment: Try using 192.168.0.102:8080

Comment: Looks like 192.168.0.1 is your router gateway, not the server host. Can you run ipconfig or ifconfig and attach the result?